# Multiple podspec files in a single git repository

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cocoapods

I have an [open source project](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Reach) written in Swift. I want to support both Swift 1.2 and 2.0. So I created two versions of the library for each Swift version and placed them inside two separate directories.

I want to add CocoaPods support for both versions. So I created two *.podspec* files and placed them in those separate directories.
 This is the one I created for the Swift 1.2 version.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = 'Reach'
  spec.version = '1.0.0'
  spec.summary = 'A simple class to check for internet connection availability in Swift.'
  spec.homepage = 'https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Reach'
  spec.license = 'MIT'
  spec.author = { 'Isuru Nanayakkara' => 'isuru.nan@gmail.com' }
  spec.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Reach.git', :tag => "#{spec.version}" }
  spec.source_files = 'Reach-swift1.2/Reach.swift'
  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.frameworks = 'SystemConfiguration'
end
```

I can define it in the *Podfile* like this.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Reach', :git => 'https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Reach.git'
```

Now I'm faced with a problem. I can't use that same way in a Swift 2.0 project since in the *podspec* file, the `source_files` field is pointed to the `Reach.swift` file in the *Reach-swift1.2* directory.

How can I resolve this issue? Is it possible to do this in CocoaPods?

Comment: did you achieved the solution?

Comment: @SanyasiraoMopada No, apparently it's not possible.